# Python-like JS Interpreter using V8

Tags: javascript, interpreter, v8

Inspired by node.js, I decided to look for a standalone, Python-like JavaScript interpreter using V8 (which is faster than Python in some cases). I haven't found any solution besides [one standard library project on github](https://github.com/sebastien/k7), which seems dead and poor man's "shell" from V8 samples.

Features I'm looking for:

- extendibility,
- rich standard library,
- possibility to save compiled bytecode,
- easy to write for,
- great OOP features,
- multi-platform.

Question is: **have you ever heard of such JS interpreter?**

Comment: It seems you have mild terminology mixup. Are you asking for a language with a V8-based interpreter? A V8-esque implementation of Python? A stdlib for JS?

Comment: I'm looking for an JS interpreter which would share given features with Python. Sorry, will form my question more precisely.

Comment: Some of the features you name aren't part of a JS interpreter. They could be part of a different language, but JS is pretty much set in stone - including e.g. its OOP model. And the most "standard" a library will ever get is "runs on the major implementations" unless ECMA steps up and buys some batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at Coffee Script.  It has a nice clean syntax, compiles to JavaScript, and borrows ideas from Python and Ruby. http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/